# why aspx requires {} in if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering why do we have to wrap if statement with <%{%> And <%}%> for any if condition in aspx.

For example this code works:

```
<% if (contidtion) { %>
    <%= DoSomething() %>
<%}%>
```

But this code doesn't work :

```
<% if (contidtion) { %>
    <%= DoSomething()
  }
 %>
```

Can you please explain the difference between those 2 conditions. And why the first one does work and why the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the definition of what the <%= %> tag does. It does the same thing as Response.Write().

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(VS.71).aspx

Meaning, it will output whatever the evaluated expression is inside. If you do not close the tag before if's closing "}", the "}" is considered as part of the expression inside your Response.Write(). That is why it isn't considered a closing } for the if statement.